# XPCOM error in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

help me
this log in termial
Starting kaiosrt-bin
Running: /mnt/c/Users/Bao Nam/Downloads/kaiosrt/kaiosrt-bin --profile /mnt/c/Users/Bao Nam/Downloads/kaiosrt/gaia/profile
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /mnt/c/Users/Bao Nam/Downloads/kaiosrt/libxul.so:
libasound.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.